# Subtract this year from starting year in business to get total years using javascript in a wordpress text field

Tags: javascript, wordpress

currently i use this code to get THIS YEAR.  it works.  I want to be able to 2000 from this year to get total years in business.  Can you help me modify this code? thx

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

`document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = (new Date().getFullYear() - 2000)`

This returns `22`, the total number of years in business.